# Mongoid unscoped model causing other model to be unscoped

Tags: ruby, mongoid, activemodel

I'm using default scopes in Mongoid, and have seen some odd behavior.

I have two models in question, call them Category and Item. Item `belongs_to` Category, although in testing, this seems to not matter. Both models have a status field (with different names), and I have a default scope on both models related to this status field.

When I pass a block to `Category.unscoped`, it removes the default scope from Item, as well. Here's what an example callsite looks like:

```
Category.unscoped do
  # these are equal, when I do not want them to be
  Item.count == Item.unscoped.count

  # these are unequal, even though I want them to be the same
  Item.count != Item.where({status: {"$ne" => "trash"}}).count
end
```

**My question is**: is there a way to use default scopes which will allow `Category.unscoped` to remove the default scope from Category, *without* removing default scopes from other models, such as Item?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're using `Category.unscoped do ... end` to wrap an `Item` query.

Comment: I'm using `Category.unscoped do ... end` to wrap a collection of logic, some of which includes an `Item` query. For instance, in the real code, there's an `Item` query which involves converting a `category_id` (from the web request) into an `Item.where({category: cat, ...})` query.

Comment: But why `Category.unscoped` in particular? The block form seems to apply itself to every single Mongoid query inside the block rather than just to `Category` queries, the `unscoped` code suggests this and the behavior you're seeing suggests this. I'm guessing that you're going to have to do it by hand with lots of `unscoped` calls or maybe `Category.unscoped.tap do |categories| ... end` if you want to keep using the block. The block form of `unscoped` seems poorly conceived and implemented to me but there's nothing we can do about that.

Comment: Ah, does the implementation itself suggest that block form `unscoped` applies to *all* models, not just the model that you call it on? If that's the case, "no, you can't, because of [code details]" would be a good answer! As for why I'm doing it: the Mongoid documentation says that "You can tell Mongoid not to apply the default scope by using `unscoped`" - saying "the default scope", rather than "any default scopes", made me think that it would only apply to the model that I'm calling it on.

Comment: Check the [source code](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/scopable.rb) yourself and search for `without_default_scope` and judge for yourself. I don't even use Mongoid anymore so I'm not really sure WTF it is doing. The behavior you're seeing doesn't make sense to me, how the code works doesn't make sense to me, the mere existence of `Category.unscoped do ... end` doesn't make much sense to me :)

Comment: Much appreciated! That at least gives me a direction for further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

For information this issue has been fixed in recent releases of mongoid:

[without_default_scope suppresses default scopes of other models](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-4630)